# In JavaScript when I create my functions and variables inside objects how can I avoid using "this" every time?

Tags: javascript

I am using simple JavaScript objects which hold functions and members
the problem is that each time I am using one of the members or functions i have to add the `this`.
Writing `this` adds more work so how can I avoid using it before every member variable or member function?

For example :

```
var MyClass = cc.LayerColor.extend({
    sprite:null,
    stopGameLoop:false,
    labelScore:null,
    winSize:0,
    visibleOrigin:0,
    blocksList : [] ,
    circle:null,
    gameOverScreen:null,
    circleblockY:0,
    circleblockX:0, 
    blocksNum:0,
    currentState:0,
    zCount:0,
    currentZorder:0,
    iScore:0,


    ctor:function () {
        //////////////////////////////
        // 1. super init first
        this._super();
        this.init( cc.color(255,255,255, 255) ); 
        this.winSize = cc.winSize;
        this.visibleOrigin = cc.director.getVisibleOrigin(); 

        this.setGameOverScreen(this.blocksNum);                 
        this.setLevel(this.circleblockY,this,circleblockX);
        return true;
    },
    setLevel:function (a,b,c) {
    },
    setGameOverScreen:function (foo) {
    },


});
```

Always using , `this` why?

Comment: There's no real general solution compatible with modern JS. The freedom of JS compared to some languages with an implicit this comes with the need to be explicit when referring to the holder of a property.

Comment: you can eliminate the `this.` if you use functions instead of methods (don't attach them to the class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to object properties, so you have to tell the JavaScript engine what object you want to read them from; there is no implicit `this` like there is in Java or C#. The reference you're using is `this`, so you have to use `this.` in the code.

It's *possible* to dump all of the properties of an object into scope, using the `with` construct, but doing so is **strongly discouraged** — so strongly, in fact, that when TC-39 (the committee that steers JavaScript) released ES5 in 2009, they added a new "strict mode" to do various things, and one of those things is to disallow `with` entirely in strict mode.

Using an explicit object reference is just how it's done in JavaScript.

There are other styles of programming in JavaScript that don't use `this`, some of which can largely avoid using an object reference through manipulating closures, but looking at your code they wouldn't be compatible with the framework/library you're using. Others avoid `this` but still have an explicit object reference (e.g., `foo.`), so that wouldn't really help.

Of course, if you just want it to be shorter, you can alias it to a variable:

```
var t = this;
t._super();
t.init(/*...*/);
```

*(Presuming the lib you're using doesn't use function decompilation to look expressly for `this`, which some used to, but hopefully these days nothing modern does...)*

...but frankly I suggest just getting comfortable with `this`.

Comment: @user63898: I'm sorry, I have no idea what "same same t this" is meant to mean.

Comment: Just wondering: is this possible in es6: this[a,b]=[function(){},"var"]; ?

Comment: @Jonasw: That syntax will work, but it won't do what you probably want it to do; I don't know because you  haven't said what you want it to do. What it *will* do is set `this[b]` to an array containing a function and a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a constructor, meaning that you are using this function to create an object. The object is `this`. You need to specify that you are doing all those things to `this`. Its an intentional thing, not a bug, and there is no reason at all to change it. If you need to use it in another function, or in `setTimeout`, you can declare a new variable, and make it refer to `this` by doing this: `var that = this;`